# Парсинг данных из INI файла (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ini

Коллеги, каким образом можно привести данные из текстового файла записанные следующим образом (вероятно формат *.INI file):

```
['2016-04-18',12],['2016-04-19',22],['2016-04-21',345],['2016-04-22',322],['2016-04-22',122] и т.д.
```

к нормальному *.CSV виду используя Python? Т.е. дата и величина в итоге, должны быть в разных столбцах.

Comment: Если честно, то на ум приходит идея очистить файл от знаков "[]'," и использовать в качестве разделителя пробел.

Comment: @qwerty только не пробел, а запятую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не формат INI файла, это больше похоже на обычный питоновский список без начальных и конечных квадратных скобок. Соответственно, можно эти скобки добавить, и распрасить с помощью `ast.literal_eval` как питоновский список:

```
text = "['2016-04-18',12],['2016-04-19',22],['2016-04-21',345],['2016-04-22',322],['2016-04-22',122]"

import ast
from pprint import pprint

data = ast.literal_eval("[" + text + "]")
pprint(data)
```

Результат:

```
[['2016-04-18', 12],
 ['2016-04-19', 22],
 ['2016-04-21', 345],
 ['2016-04-22', 322],
 ['2016-04-22', 122]]
```

Если нужно сохранить в csv:

```
import csv

with open("result.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Если собираетесь обрабатывать эти данные с помощью pandas, то сразу преобразовывайте список с dataframe без промежуточного сохранения в csv:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date", "number"])
# или
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=["date", "number"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('<your_file>') as f:
    s = f.readline()
    s = s.replace('],[', '\n')
    s = s.replace('[', '')
    s = s.replace(']', '')
```

В файле:

```
['2016-04-18',12],['2016-04-19',22],['2016-04-21',345],['2016-04-22',322],['2016-04-22',122]
```

В результате в `s`:

```
'2016-04-18',12
'2016-04-19',22
'2016-04-21',345
'2016-04-22',322
'2016-04-22',122
```